# `ReactApp/App.js`: Module 'react' does not exist in the Haste Module map - following instructions of iOS simulator with no success

Tags: react-native, module

I'm running 'react-native run-ios' for a new react app i'm init but I keep getting this error.

I followed through the instructions given by the debugger in iOS simulator but unfortunately the problem is persisting.

Has anyone experienced the same problem and knows another solution other than the one presented in the IOS simulator? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. can you send a screenshot? or Send the error completely. Which version are you installing? What node version do you have?